# What's the Difference in jQuery Selectors?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here's a list of selectors I've seen before:

1. `$('.menu')`
2. `$('menu')`
3. `$('#menu')`

Could anyone clarify in what scenario(s) each would be used?

Comment: checkout this tut on selectors, sometimes best way is 2 see code in action http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eQI90xYez0  http://tutorialvid.com/viewVideo.php?video_id=MTM4Mw==&title=Introduction_to_jQuery_JavaScript_Framework

Comment: Whatever happened to reading the manual?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. `$('.menu')` ... select elements with `class='menu'`
2. `$('menu')`  ..... select `<menu />` elements
3. `$('#menu')` ... select an element with `id='menu'`

Answer (score 5):

1st finds `<div class="menu"></div>`

2nd finds `<menu></menu>`

3rd finds `<div id="menu"></div>`

Note that these rules applies and are based on CSS.

Comment: And to be even more clear, the rules are not based on CSS.  `.menu` is a CSS class, however the selectors are parsing the DOM with Javascript.  The other two have nothing to do with CSS.

Answer (score 3):

$('.menu'): all element with a class menu

$('menu'): all menu element

$('#menu'): the element with an id of menu

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.menu') -> <div class="menu"></div> or any other tag with class menu
$('menu')  -> <menu></menu>
$('#menu') -> <div id="menu"></div> or any other tag with id menu
```

Answer (score 2):

Class Selector (“.class”)
Selects all elements with the given class.

Element Selector (“element”)
Selects all elements with the given tag name.

ID Selector (“#id”)
Selects a single element with the given id attribute.

**Reference:**
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery selector syntax is the same as that of css. So ".menu" will select everything with a class of menu, "#menu" will select the object with an id of menu (there should only be one! "menu" will try to select elements of type menu.

An example;

```
<div class="foo" id="d1">Div 1</div>
<div class="foo" id="d2">Div 2</div>

<span class="foo" id="s1">Span 1</span>
<span class="foo" id="s2">Span 2</span>

$(".foo").css("background", "red"); //sets the background of all 4 elements to red
$("div").css("background", "blue"); //sets the background of the two divs to blue
$("#s1").css("background", "green"); //sets the background of span 1 to green
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://forum.codecall.net/javascript-tutorials/14363-jquery-selectors.html

```
#id: -> This will match any element with the given ID.

element -> This will match any element supplied.

.class  -> This will match any element with the given class.
```