# What is wrong with this Autocomplete Code (JQuery-UI AutoComplete)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, autocomplete

```
$("#Auto").autocomplete({
minLength: 4,
type: 'GET',
source: function (request, response) {
    var term = request.term;
    if (term in cache) {
        response(cache[term]);
        return;
    }
    var url = '<%=Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Thing", new {area = "Admin"}) %>' + "?terms=" + request.term;
    lastXhr = $.getJSON(url, request, function (data, status, xhr) {
        cache[term] = data;
        if (xhr === lastXhr) {
            response(data);
        }
    });
}
})
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
          return $("<li></li>")
.data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a> Thingy1: " + item.Prop1 + " Thingy2: " + item.Prop2 + "<br>" + "</a>")
    .appendTo(ul);
      };
```

Assume #Auto, Prop1 and Prop2 exist and there is a controller called Thing. This does work on another page but for some reason I get this error on a page:

```
$("#Auto").autocomplete({minLength: 4, type: "GET", source: function (request, response);var term = request.term;if (term in cache) {response(cache[term]);return;}var url = '<%=Url.Action("AutoComplete", "Thing", new {area = "Admin"}) %>' + "?terms=" + request.term;lastXhr = $.getJSON(url, request, function (data, status, xhr) {cache[term] = data;if (xhr === lastXhr) {response(data);}});}}).data("autocomplete") is undefined
```

I have the following files loaded:

```
jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js
jquery-1.4.2.min.js
jquery.autocomplete.pack.js
jquery.ajaxQueue.js
jquery.bgiframe.min.js
thickbox-compressed.js
jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css
jquery-require.1.1.packed.js
```

plus some other custom stuff.

Is there anything I am missing, or do I have too many files included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, cleaning up your code (which looks to be lazily cut & pasted) and explaining what you are trying to do would help.

However, at first glance I can see your error says:

> .data("autocomplete") is undefined

Which would imply that no elements called "autocomplete" exist on the page.
Try changing

`.data("autocomplete")`

to

`.data("#Auto")`

if you are trying to store the data contained in your autocomplete control for later use.

Comment: will .data("autocomplete") recognize an element with this class: ui-autocomplete-input?

Comment: No.  `("autocomplete")` is a selector that will looking for an `<autocomplete />` element.  If you want that class you need to use `('.ui-autocomplete-input')` but I'm not sure that's what you want.  You should try explaining in non-programming language first what you are trying to do.

Comment: My explanation of basic jQuery selectors can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7664384/whats-the-difference-in-jquery-selectors/7664407#7664407)

Comment: I am trying to use JQuery UI to make an AutoComplete for a textbox. The box has an ID called Auto. I am using the AutoComplete found here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: I can see that, but you have drastically customized the plugin to a level even the most seasoned jQuery users would find complex.  So I assume you copied the code and tailored some of it for your purposes in which case you have left something out or added something wrong.  Try using the autocomplete plugin in its basic form first, then make modifications slowly so you can see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to say Terry's response is wrong. Your code is not an element selector. The `data` function is used to retrieve a data object that's been linked to an HTML element. In your case, you're retrieving the data linked to the element with id `Auto`.

```
var data = $("#Auto").data("autocomplete");
// data is now an object stored by the autocomplete plugin.
```

Your problem seems to imply that no data with key `autocomplete` could be found. I'm not sure how that could happen unless your autocomplete script isn't doing their job.

Answer (score 0):

Dysprosium is wrong, not Terry.  Here is a source link of the change: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-data-fallbacks-for-widget-names

dialog is now ui-dialog, or uiDialog, autocomplete is now ui-autocomplete, etc. ect.